# 15 puzzle game in java

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I am creating a 15 puzzle game in java. I have already created a game panel and written method that finds the position of the empty place (not JButton) on a field and a method that controls whether it is a winning combitanion or not (JButtons on a correct places). So, I got something like this:

[image]

I have a trouble with writing an ActionListener. Is it possible to write a method that determines that actionListener should be added to the JButtons that surround the empty space.

I really need some tips or/maybe already written methods/solutions.

Thanks!

Comment: I thought this was a good question, until I read "maybe already written methods/solutions". You'll probably get better help/ideas if you omit this in the future.

Comment: *"So, I got something like this:"*  A picture might paint a thousand words, but an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) paints a *very* specific picture.

Comment: @Andrew If I had a dollar for every comment asking for an SSCCE where one wasn't necessary, I could retire. :-) They're useful in some situations but in this case OP was perfectly capable of explaining his problem without one.

Comment: @glowcoder  *"They're useful in some situations but in this case OP was perfectly capable of explaining his problem"*  That is just one of many reasons for which posting an SSCCE is a useful way to transmit a code problem.  One of the other many reasons is that they might also have picked up some tips on how to implement that in a code example (in answer).  If I had a dollar for every person that has commented negatively on posting an SSCCE without really understanding what it is about, *I'd* be able to retire.  ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think your best bet would be to keep the action listener active on all the buttons. When clicked, it simply does nothing if it determines itself to not be adjacent to the empty box.

Comment: or consider moving the entire row/column: so if they click 14 in the above, it becomes the empty space and 1, 13, and 14 all move left 1 position.

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend ditching the idea of only adding actionListeners to the buttons that surround the empty space: keep actionListeners added to all buttons and only process a click if it is valid.

Also, in my experience, it is very user-hostile to only allow a click on one of the tiles that surround the empty space. In the example picture, you are planning to only allow a click on 7, 1, and 11. You should allow a click on 5, 7, 1, 13, 14 and 11. So, for example a click on 14 should move 1, 13 and 14 to the left.